# The difference between English as the primary language, first language and a recognized language

Tags: meaning, difference

I'm doing an essay on the extent of the Anglophone world. I must include the following information:

- countries in which English is a first or **native** language
- countries in which English holds legal status as the **primary** language
- countries in which English holds legal status as a **secondary** language
- regions and international bodies in which English is upheld as a **recognized** language

I've been researching these online and it has left me quite perplexed. Maybe it's just me, but I feel there is a great deal of overlap among them. For example the UK can easily fall into three of these categories. I particularly do not understand **the difference between English as the primary language, first language and a recognized language** in a country. I'm guessing it must have something to do with official languages, yet I can't clearly distinguish the differences.

Could anyone make an example for each type of country?

Comment: Is this about English?

Comment: @Kentaro Donates For Monica I think so. What do those English collocations mean and is there a difference among them? I admit it might come across as rather a technical question.